# C++ increase build speed in large project by using libraries

Tags: c++, windows, performance, dll, libraries

I'm currently trying to optimise build speed for a big project with following in mind:

- build speed is priority 1
- resulting binaries size does *not* matter

**Infos:**

- Environment: Visual Studio 2012 (required, because of the software I'm developing for) + Windows machine
- BuildTime: 12mins (clean build), 1min for small changes and every now and than small changes result in 5-6min because of slow linking (this is what I want to address)
- Custom files in project: approx. 2500 (SDK I need to use excluded, a big  SDK for a CAD system)
- Lines of code in custom files: approx. 500000
- I'm using an up-to-date CAD capable computer (32GB RAM, >3GHz QuadCore, SSD)

**Ideas:**

- use precompiled headers => done, but does not have the effect I want; helps speed up compile time most of the time, but every now and than does not
- split up project into libraries => not sure if this helps

**Questions**

I could not find anything about using libraries and build speed, but I assume if I precompile libraries, the linker will be faster.

- Is this assumption true?
- If I make a static library with the core functions, will this have an effect on build time? Or will the linker need as long as it does currently?
- If I make a dynamic library, will this have an effect on build time? Or will the linker again check the dll completely and will need the same time?

Comment: It is operating system specific (Windows DLLs are very different of shared libraries on Linux). Consider using a good [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/). Show your compilation commands (or your `Makefile`). Tell more about your project (how many millions of lines, what is it doing, what libraries it is using)

Comment: Added my build environment, I'm stuck to an older VS version and a windows computer

Comment: Better put a Windows tag. AFAIK Windows don't have shared libraries but DLLs (with a weird linking scheme). And you should tell much more about your project (how many source files, how many millions lines of source code). AFAIK `make` is also used on Windows, and you could build GNU `make` or `ninja` from their source code and use them with Visual Studio compiler, since they both are free software.

Comment: Without much more details the question stays unclear and too broad. You could read Levine's [linkers and loaders](http://iecc.com/linkers/) book; but I strongly recommend using a good external build automation tool (e.g. `ninja` compiled from its source)

Comment: Added some general informations... Not sure what else I should add. It is a general question actually

Comment: Did you consider switching to `ninja` but still using (on command line, thru `ninja`) your Visual Studio compiler (with appropriate compiler switches). BTW 12 minutes is a short full build time. When building [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Qt](http://qtr.io/) from its source code, it can take hours.

Comment: Not yet. I need to compile in a very special way so that the CAD will be able to recognise and load my libraries (i.e. v110_xp platform toolset) and other settings must be met as well (sadly undefined). The CAD and SDK officially only support VS + v110_xp platform and so I'm not sure if I could even use ninja...

Answer (score 1):

12 minutes is a short full build time and 500KLOC is not that big. Many free software projects ([GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), Qt, ...) have longer ones (hours) and millions of C++ lines.

You might want to use a serious and parallel [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, such as [ninja](http://ninjka-build.org/). Perhaps you could do some distributed build (like what [distcc](https://github.com/distcc) permits) if you can compile on remote machines.

You could configure your IDE to run an external command (such as `ninja`) for builds. This don't change autocompletion abilities. You could adopt another [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (e.g. [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)).

C++ is not (yet) modular (it does not have genuine modules, like e.g. Ocaml or Go), and that makes its compilation slow (e.g. because standard container headers are big, e.g. `<vector>` brings about 10KLOC of included code, probably used and *included* in most of your C++ code). So you should **avoid having many small files** (e.g. merging two files of 250 lines each into one of 500 lines could decrease build time) and it looks like you have too much small C++ files. I would recommend *source files of more than a thousand lines each*. Having only one class implementation (or one function) per source file slows down the total build time.

You surely want to use more indirection in your code. Use more systematically [PIMPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) idioms and [virtual method tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), closures, `std::function`-s. Remember the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 1):

> I assume if I precompile libraries, the linker will be faster. Is this assumption true?

No, not likely. If at all (because the linker has to open fewer files), then the difference will be marginal.

> If I make a static library with the core functions, will this have an effect on build time? Or will the linker need as long as it does currently?

It may make a huge difference on *compile* time, since although on a truly clean rebuild you still have to compile everything as before, on a normal "mostly clean" rebuild rebuilding the support libraries is superfluous since nothing ever changes inside them, so all you really need to rebuild is the user code, and as a result you compile a lot fewer files.
Note that every sane build system normally builds a dependency graph and tries to compile as few files as possible anyway (and, to the extent possible, with some level of parallelism), unless you *explicitly* tell it to do a clean build (which is rarely necessary to be done). Doctor, it hurts when I do this -- well, don't do it.

The difference for the linker will, again, be marginal. The linker still needs to look up the exact same amount of symbols, and still needs to copy the same amount of code into the executable.

You may want to play with link order. Funny as it sounds, sometimes the order in which libraries and object files are linked makes a 5x difference on how long it takes the linker to do its job.

That being said, 12 minutes for a clean build indeed isn't a lot. Your non-clean buils will likely be in the two-digit second range, of which linking probably takes 90%. That's normally not a showstopper. Come back when a build takes 4 hours :-)

> If I make a dynamic library, will this have an effect on build time? Or will the linker again check the dll completely and will need the same time?

The linker will still have to do some work for every function you call, which might be *slightly* faster, but will still be *more or less* the same.

Note that you add runtime (startup) overhead by moving code into a DLL. It is more work for the loader to load a program with parts of the code in a DLL as it needs to load another image, parse its header, resolve symbols, set up some pointers, run per-thread init functions, etc. That's usually not an issue (the difference is not really that much noticeable), just letting you know it's not free.

Comment: So for compile time optimisation, using libraries (static or dynamic) won't make a noticeable difference, all I can do is optimise my code (includes, settings, ...), correct?

Comment: Whether or not a library or an executable is built makes _zero_ difference for the compilation. In every case, for each translation unit, one object file is generated. Whether that's put into one or another "container" before finally landing in the executable is vastly the same (and not the scope of compilation). Include files and templates can indeed greatly influence compile times, in unhealthy cases possibly by 10x overall (but they do **not** affect link time, which you state as the problem). Well, that's only 99% true, there's `#pragma` directives which _do_ affect link time...